# JavaScript indexOf String Function 2nd argument is not working

Tags: javascript

For some reason, my indexOf 2nd arg (where to start the search) is not working. It just always returns 4 or -1.
Where string test = "Bob jr" and I am using built-in JavaScript console on about:blank:

```
> var test = "Bob jr";
> test.indexOf('j', 0);
< 4 = $3
> test.indexOf('j', 1);
< 4 = $3
> test.indexOf('j', 12);
< -1 = $2
```

Why is this not working and how can I get it working?

Comment: as the `j` doesn't move, it would be in the same place every time - in other words, the returned value isn't relative to the start position of the search

Answer (score 6):

Whether you start looking at `0` or index `1`, the `j` is still at index `4`.

Your final example proves the argument *does* work, because you said to start after the `j` (beyond the end of the string entirely), and sure enough, it didn't find it.

Let's see `indexOf`'s second argument in action:

```js
var str = "j and j and j x";
console.log("Search string: '" + str + "'");
for (var n = 0; n < str.length; ++n) {
    test(str, n);
}
function test(s, start) {
    var index = s.indexOf("j", start);
    console.log("Starting at " + start + ": " + index);
}
```

If you want to find out how far after the index you've given it is to the `j`, you can do that in two ways:

1. Subtract your index from the result you get:

   ```
    console.log("Distance: " + (test.indexOf('j', 1) - 1));
   ```
2. Search a substring:

   ```
    console.log("Distance: " + test.substring(1).indexOf('j');
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation of [`indexOf here`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
str.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])
```

There is no `j` after position 12 and that is why you are getting -1 in the last case.

Answer (score 0):

indexOf always return the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, [starting the search at fromIndex.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)  The reason your return value isn't changing is because "j" is still the 5th character in your string, regardless of whether you begin your search a few characters into the string.